# Logging SELECT statements in PostgreSQL 8.4

Tags: sql, postgresql, logging, select, rules

I've got a table which contains sensitive data and according to data protection policy we have to keep a record of every read/write of the data including a row identifier and the user who accessed the table. The writing is no issue using triggers but triggers aren't supported for `SELECT` statements.

What's the best method of doing this? I've looked at rules but I can't get them to `INSERT` into a table, and I've tried logging every query but this doesn't seem to log `SELECT` statements. Ideally for security I'd like to keep the log within a table on the database but logging to a file is fine too.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could enable SENTENCE LOGGING in PostgreSQL:

In postgresql.conf:

```
log_statement = 'all'                   # none, ddl, mod, all
```

Then restart your database and all senteces will be logged.

Answer (score 1):

You can take either take the log files and import them into the database using the [cvslog format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG), or setup something like [syslog-ng](http://ben.muppethouse.com/SYSLOG-DOC.html) to put the messages back into postgres or some other database.